# how to get current user with Django’s class-based views

Tags: django

`NameError: name 'request' is not defined`

```
class PostListViewPrv(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(wszyscy=False, pracownik=request.user, published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2
    template_name = 'komunikaty/komunikatyPrv.html'
```

variable pracownik should contain the username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to override `get_queryset()`:

```py
class PostListViewPrv(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "posts"
    paginate_by = 2
    template_name = "komunikaty/komunikatyPrv.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(
            wszyscy=False,
            pracownik=self.request.user,
            published_date__lte=timezone.now(),
        ).order_by("-published_date")
```

Comment: You might want to check for `self.request.user.is_authenticated` and raise a forbidden/unauthorized error if this view should not be public (unless it's already wrapped in `login_required`).